# How do I add a <table> using Element with Prototype in IE6?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

Using Prototype 1.6's "new Element(...)" I am trying to create a <table> element with both a <thead> and <tbody> but nothing happens in IE6.

```
var tableProto = new Element('table').update('<thead><tr><th>Situation Task</th><th>Action</th><th>Result</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody>');
```

I'm then trying to inject copies of it like this:

```
$$('div.question').each(function(o) {
  Element.insert(o, { after:$(tableProto.cloneNode(true)) });
});
```

My current workaround is to create a <div> instead of a <table> element, and then "update" it with all of the table HTML.

How does one successfully do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, there's nothing wrong with the example code I provided in the question--it works in IE6 just fine. The issue I was facing is that I was also specifying a class for the <table> element in the constructor incorrectly, but omitted that from my example.

The "real" code was as follows, and is incorrect:

```
var tableProto = new Element('table', { class:'hide-on-screen'} ).update('<thead><tr><th>Situation Task</th><th>Action</th><th>Result</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody>');
```

This works correctly in Firefox, but fails in IE6 because it is **wrong**.

The correct way to add attributes to an element via this constructor is to provides strings, not just attribute names. The following code works in both browsers:

```
var tableProto = new Element('table', { 'class':'hide-on-screen'} ).update('<thead><tr><th>Situation Task</th><th>Action</th><th>Result</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody>');
```

There is an error due to "class" being a reserved word in JavaScript. Doh!

Let this be a lesson to those who don't supply their **actual** code!

Comment: alternatively, you could've used className instead of class. http://www.prototypejs.org/2007/5/12/dom-builder#comment-15777

Answer (score 2):

If prototypes' .update() method internally tries to set the .innerHTML it will fail in IE.  In IE, **the .innerHTML of a table element is readonly**.

Source:

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/12/bug-210-no-innerhtml-support-on-tables.html